# NodeJS Express: json not being included in response

Tags: json, node.js

I've written a super simple server that takes `POST` requests with a name, and writes the name to a file, `GET`s return all the names, and `DELETE`s delete the name file.  My problem is in the `DELETE` method.  When I send a 205 to indicate that the names file was deleted, the JSON is being included in the response, but when I send the 204, indicating that no file exists to delete, the response comes back empty.

Here's the method defining the behavior:

```
function clearNames(req, res) {
    fs.unlink('names.txt', function(err){
        if (err) {
            res.status(204).json({'success': true});
        } else {
            res.status(205).json({'success': true});
        }
    });
}
```

and here's the result.  The first request is sent when a name file exists, and deletes the file.  The second is sent after the file is deleted, so no file exists to delete:

```
$ curl -X DELETE -w ' %{http_code}' http://localhost:18080/api/names 
{"success":true} 205
$ curl -X DELETE -w ' %{http_code}' http://localhost:18080/api/names 
 204
$
```

Comment: You should use `404 Not found` response status code, instead of `204 No content`. Besides of this, why do you need json, which is the same in both cases, response status code is enough to determinate the result of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error-case you're sending a status 204, which means "No content", and thus the client doesn't expect any content after that. Change the status to something that would include a response body and it should work.

Quote from the [specs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

A 205 status shouldn't also include a body, so I suggest you change it as well.